# How to add prefix in product URL using custom module

Tags: magento2, products-management

I am using the following code to add prefix but it returns the Url with Two prefixes(http://localhost/magento/product/product/test-product.html):

```
<?php
namespace Magegk\Addprefix\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite;

class ProductUrlPathGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator
{

    // CHANGE THESE FOR CUSTOM STATIC PREFIX ROUTE of PRODUCT and PRODUCT CATEGORY
    const PRODUCT_PREFIX_ROUTE = 'product';
    const CATEGORY_PREFIX_ROUTE = 'product-category';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($storeManager, $scopeConfig, $categoryUrlPathGenerator, $productRepository);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Product Url path (with category if exists)
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrlPath($product, $category = null)
    {
        $path = $product->getData('url_path');
        if ($path === null) {
            $path = $product->getUrlKey()
                ? $this->prepareProductUrlKey($product)
                : $this->prepareProductDefaultUrlKey($product);
        }

        if ($category !== null) {
            $categoryUrl = str_replace(self::CATEGORY_PREFIX_ROUTE .'/','',$this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category));
            $path = $categoryUrl . '/' . $path;
        }

        return self::PRODUCT_PREFIX_ROUTE . $path;
    }
}
```

please help in finding out the mistake..

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you need to check this URL.

https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-add-prefix-to-store-products-urls-in-magento-2/